# Строка поиска и элементы управления (дизайн, css)

Tags: html, css, responsive, дизайн, adaptive-design

Помогите сделать резиновый блок со строкой поиска и дополнительными элементами.

**Обязательно:**

- Все элементы в одну строку,
- box2 прижат в право,
- поле input занимает все оставшееся пространство

https://jsfiddle.net/bsgh3cro/16/

```css
body{
  width:100%;
}

.main{}

.box1{}

.box2{}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

  <div class="main">
  
    <div class="box1">
      <input type="text" value="Search">
      <span><i class="lni lni-search-alt"></i></span>
      <span><i class="lni lni-close"></i></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box2">
      <span><i class="lni lni-heart"></i></span>
      <span><i class="lni lni-funnel"></i></span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
}

.box1{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

  <div class="main">
  
    <div class="box1">
      <input type="text" value="Search">
      <span><i class="lni lni-search-alt"></i></span>
      <span><i class="lni lni-close"></i></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box2">
      <span><i class="lni lni-heart"></i></span>
      <span><i class="lni lni-funnel"></i></span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Да, уже сделал с помощью flexbox. Спасибо! Но может кто еще что предложит?